HTML & CSS Header
Hello I am trying to create my own version of an existing website, but I can't seem to copy their header, below is my code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400);

        #logo {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-top: 0.3125rem;
            padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            margin-left: 5rem;
            margin-right: 1rem;
            line-height: inherit;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
                display: none;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {
                position: relative;
            }

            .topnav.responsive a.icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            .topnav.responsive a {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }
        }

        nav {
            flex-grow: 1;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav ul li {
            margin: 0 1vw;
        }

        .topnav {
            background-color: #252323 !important;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 1rem 1rem;
            position: sticky;
            width: 100%;
           

        }

        a{
            color: white;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }



        .topnav #hover:hover {
            background-color: #1F9BDE;
            color: white;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;

        }

        .topnav a.active {
            color: orange;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        .page{
          
            padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
            margin: 1% 1%;
            border: none;
           
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Poppins;

            font-weight: 400;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        
        }

        .btn {
            padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
            margin: 1% 1%;
            border: none;
            background-color: orange;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Poppins;

            font-weight: 400;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav" id="topnav">
        <a href="#"> <img id="logo" src="ActiveLearningLogo.png"> </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>

                <li class="page" id="hover" style="float:right"><a href="#">Applicants</a></li>
                <li class="page" id="hover" style="float:right"><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
                <li class="page" id="hover" style="float:right"><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
                <li class="btn" id="hover" style="float:right"><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

this is how it looks like when minimized
enter image description here
and this is t originally
enter image description here
im trying to do this header
and this is it minimized
i am just starting in HTML and CSS so i am new to most of these things but I do wish someone can help

Since you're just starting out, I would recommend you try doing it yourself, it will probably be less work than trying to copy it. The navbar you want is pretty straight forward, you could follow the steps on w3 to learn how to create one: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp or if you want to copy/paste an existing one, I'd recommend checking out what's available on codepen: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=navbar

ID's should be unique on a page and not used multiple times.

Do some investigations around hamburger menu, the three bars you want to get the menu when the viewport is narrow.

You should specify what you exactly want. Your CSS code contains lots of mistakes, and you should filter your CSS code.
I suggest you look into the codes very well and try to find your mistakes to learn properly. You have used unnecessary flex, have targeted the same HTML element more than once, etc.
If you just want to hide the nav menu bar when the screen width is below 600px, just use display:none by targeting the nav bar inside the @media query you have used.

This is a comment, not an answer. Please delete it.
